# Usage of method

Tags: prepositions

> I devised a method **in which**  I could measure time.
>   I devised a method **with which** I could measure time

**Which**/**What** is the correct usage of method?

Should I use which or what???????

Answer (score 2):

I believe the correct sentence is

> I devised a method by which I could measure time.

Or, more simply:

> I devised a method to measure time.

"with which" works, too, but it doesn't sound nice, with the w at the start of both words. "in which" sounds like, incidentally, while using this method to do something else, I could also measure time.